# Shared folder on one mac

Tags: sharing, folders, user-account

I have two users. In "Get Info" I shared a User1 folder with the User2. But how can I access the folder from the User2 account?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "I shared", you mean that you've granted other users permissions to read and/or modify this file. But that's all this action does: Granting permissions. It's only half the way, and usually the second in order.

The simplest way (and the only one I know of) for the files to actually be shared between different users, is to have them in your "Shared" folder, which can be found in the "users" folder.

[image]

You would then access those file from this directory. For your own convenience, you can add this directory to your (left) Finder sidebar for quicker access.

There's a relatively recent and quite comprehensive article on sharing folders between users with this method over at [MacObserver](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/how-to-share-files-between-user-accounts-in-os-x).

Comment: shared folders do not HAVE to be in the /Users/Shared location, but zerohedge is probably correct that this is one of the simplest locations to provide access for others. I think that any folder(s) put or created in the /Users/Shared location will get the proper permissions to be readable by everyone on the system, but perhaps not writeable.

Comment: @j-beda I have revised my answer so it doesn't imply this is the *only* way. What is your purposed solution? I'm curious because you seem to know there are other ways, while I'm only aware of this one. Then again, I'm relatively new to OS X (< 1 year).

Comment: You should be able to change permissions on any file/folder to allow anyone to access it. However navigating to that folder in the Finder would be impossible if the enclosing folders do not also have the right permissions. Thus I could allow zerohedge read and write permissions on the folder /Users/j-beda/Documents/foo/bar/folder-for-zh/ and you would be albe to use the Finder menu item "Go" -> "Go to Folder..." to open that folder, but you would not be albe to use the Finder to click your way down to that folder becuase you would not be allowed to view the contents of /Users/j-beda/Documents